# Iron-collapse throws a error to console

Tags: polymer

I have a problem with using `iron-collapse`. When i use it throws a error to console. I have no idea.

Here is my example of template structure:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
<dom-module id="page-faq">
    <template>
        <header-layout id="header"></header-layout>
        <bread-crumb id="bread-crumb"></bread-crumb>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="faq-container">
                <div id="tabs">
                </div>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
                    <div class="collapse-container">
                        <button on-click="toggle">[[item.content.title]]</button>
                        <iron-collapse id="collapse">
                            <div class="collapse-content">
                                [[item.answer]]
                            </div>
                        </iron-collapse>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer-layout id="footer"></footer-layout>
    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    class PageFaq extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'page-faq'
        }

        toggle() {
            this.$.collapse.toggle();
            this.$.button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.$.collapse.opened);
        };
    }
    customElements.define(PageFaq.is, PageFaq);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And when i click button it gives me

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined`

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Comment: Your `iron-collapse` component is inside of a `<template>`. This means you must use the shadow-dom selectors to retrieve the element by ID. See the [Polymer Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template#preserve-template-contents)

Comment: Can you show me a example ?

Comment: Oh i found the solution thank you so much @EvanBechtol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is the hard way, but I don't blame you because the documentation is misguiding. There is one easier way – and more following the Polymer thinking – to control `iron-collapse`, and that's with a variable. I named it `ironCollapsableOpened` in this case.

```
                   <button on-click="toggle">[[item.content.title]]</button>
                    <iron-collapse opened="[[ironCollapseOpened]]">
                        <div class="collapse-content">
                            [[item.answer]]
                        </div>
                    </iron-collapse>
```

---

```
    toggle() {
      this.set('ironCollapseOpened', !this.ironCollapseOpened);
    };
```

> iron-collapse creates a collapsible block of content. By default, the
>   content will be collapsed. Use opened or toggle() to show/hide the
>   content.

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-collapse